# What is the purpose of Docker-compose and Portainer?

Tags: docker-compose, raspberry-pi, portainer

I am an engineering newbie who is trying to learn something while experimenting with Raspberry Pi. I wanted to try out Docker, so I followed along with a tutorial, which installed Docker, docker-compose and via that, Portainer.

Now I am a bit lost.
**What is the purpose of docker-compose?**
**What is the purpose of Portainer?**

And if **I want to add some container like NextCloud/openVPN** how do I do that? Thru Portainer? Or docker-compose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Portainer` is just a visualized tool for Docker suite. You can run docker commands everywhere a `portainer-agent` runs as long as you have access to it and it is **not** an official Docker product.

Docker-compose from the other is a set of docker commands as part of docker engine (community and enterprise) that will help you to orchestrate containers in a single node (PC or VM). If you want to orchestrate more than a single node, you should read about Docker-Swarm or Kubernetes.

A very nice article to understand swarm vs compose differences is [here](https://linuxhint.com/docker_compose_vs_docker_swarm/).

Portainer is just a tool on top of Docker that gives you a UI for free because Native Docker Universal Control Panel is on enterprise edition only.

Comment: @Vojtooo This is a good explanation. Please accept this as answer.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by mentioning kubernetes in addition to docker swarm

Comment: I updated the answer adding K8s as reference.